# Azure webjob error when trying to run a triggered webjob

Tags: azure-webjobs

I’m trying to write a webjob that is triggered, not one that runs continuously.

So I want the webjob to be called by a web hook, it runs and grabs an item of a queue, then exits.

I’m using the most up to date packages for this:

```
           Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions     v4.0.1
           Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions     v4.0.4
           Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ApplicationInsights      v3.0.27
           Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Console                  v5.0.0
           .Net Framwork                                    v4.7.2
```

For some reason when I run the code I’m getting the following error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Missing value for trigger parameter 'message'.'

At the line:
await jobHost.CallAsync(typeof(Program).GetMethod("ProcessQueueMessage"));

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

The full code is:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;

namespace WebJobsSDKSample
{
    public class Program
    {
        [NoAutomaticTrigger]
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage(ILogger log, [QueueTrigger("queue")] string message)
        {
            log.LogInformation(message);
        }

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
        var builder = new HostBuilder();
            builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                b.AddAzureStorage();
            });

            var host = builder.Build();
            using (host)
            {
                var jobHost = host.Services.GetService(typeof(IJobHost)) as JobHost;
                await jobHost.StartAsync();
                await jobHost.CallAsync(typeof(Program).GetMethod("ProcessQueueMessage"));
                await jobHost.StopAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you put any message to trigger this webjob?

Comment: Yes I tried placing a message in the queue first. Then I ran the code from Visual Studio. Which be the same a deploying the code to Azure and triggering from a webhook.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to use HTTP triggered binding but now you are using Queue triggered binding.

Actually, HTTP triggered binding is not supported on Azure WebJobs SDK, descript [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#webjobs-sdk-versions).

> Some binding types are **supported only in Functions**, like HTTP
> (Webhooks) and Event Grid (which is based on HTTP).

For the error, there is no problem with your code, but the connection you should check. And make sure to **add the queue message** in your connected storage account to trigger your task.

Comment: I've checked the connection by  switching the application to continuous mode.
I've added console logging using:
            builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
            {
                b.AddConsole();
            });

I now get a call stack, but its still not much of a help

Answer (score 0):

You are manually triggering the function **ProcessQueueMessage** from main without a parameter 'message'.

In your main you should use

```
using (host)
{
   await host.RunAsync();
}
```

Then follow these steps for testing:

LOCAL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started#test-locally

AZURE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started#trigger-the-function-in-azure